# If statement in jQuery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-templates

The following code **returns an error** "*Uncaught ReferenceError: size is not defined*" in Chrome if variable size is not defined:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">    
    {{if name && size}}
        <p>${name}</p>
        <p>${size}</p>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

While this code **works fine** :

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">  
    {{if name}}
        {{if size}}
            <p>${name}</p>
            <p>${size}</p>
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

Can I somehow make it work in Chrome **without using double if statement** and why does it return an error at all?

Comment: Have you tried `{{ if (name && size) }}`?

Comment: Post your object, maybe the object doesn't contain `size` or `size` is in other level than with `name`.

Comment: Alexander, yes, i've tried. Snake Eyes, the object doesn't contain size. The if statement is there to check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">    
    {{if name && size != null && size}}
        <p>${name}</p>
        <p>${size}</p>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work for me. Would anyone care to confirm/update?

Comment: identical error (except with a different object property name). I've ended up using the double if statement. This was a couple of fields in a relatively large template.

Comment: @penguat, try using an `isset($variable)` check instead of `!= null`... Hopefully that helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">    
    {{if (name != null && size != null)}}
        <p>${name}</p>
        <p>${size}</p>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

Note the space after if statement.